# Recovering files in Android phone, phone stuck in boot loop

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, usb-debugging

My phone is currently stuck in a boot loop. I tried using minimal adb and fastboot but I can't seem to do it. I have also read in some forums that usb debugging should be enable and the phone should be rooted. Is there a way to use adb commands without enabling the usb debugging('coz I can't). I tried all the choices in the recovery mode except the factory reset. Can somebody help me?  I really need to recover the memos that I have saved. I have a Samsung galaxy V duos. Thanks. I'm also new to adb :(

Comment: are you using stock recovery or custom?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to use adb commands without enabling the [USB] debugging[?]

There is no point pondering about this once you understand the concept. In order to communicate with device using [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) you need to have adb [daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29) running at Android's end. Additionally, for successful communication, you may also be required to authorize debugging at Android's end.

Android starts the adb daemon only when it finds the USB debugging setting under Developer options enabled. If it was enabled but was explicitly disabled by a user, the daemon would be stopped. It would be started again by Android should the setting be toggled.

If you've an another device with a terminal app installed and USB debugging enabled, do

```
ps | grep "adbd"
```

You would see an output similar to

```
shell     161   1     4564   284   ffffffff 00000000 S /sbin/adbd
```

<sub>(`shell` is the group name with ID `2000`. This is the same ID that you would see when you get a successful shell session using `adb shell`.)</sub>

Disable the debugging option and the daemon would be stopped by Android. Use the same `ps` command with `grep` and it would give you nothing.

---

As for recovering the data in this situation, keep any hope as long as you've a custom [recovery](/questions/tagged/recovery) installed. They often always run adb daemon without any complexity of authorization from user. Then you can use `adb pull` to  copy whatsoever data you want.

---

Related reading: [Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)