# Recover photos from S6 Edge+ stuck in boot loop

Tags: data-recovery, boot-loop

I have a Galaxy S6 Edge+, Android 7.0 that did something weird.  I restarted it and now it's stuck in a boot loop.  I don't care if it gets wiped, but I want to get the pictures off it first.  It gets to the Samsung logo and hangs there for several minutes and will eventually restart itself.  In the meantime, I can connect via ADB and I would just pull all the files, but the data partition isn't mounted at /mnt/sdcard at this point.  I've tried the obvious, but no luck...

- Stock recovery menu accessible
- Wiping cache does not help
- Cannot boot into safe mode
- Firmware download mode accessible
- Not rooted
- USB debugging enabled
- OEM unlock not enabled

I heard that flashing stock firmware would get it working again and not wipe the data partition.  If this is the way to go, is there a reliable source where I can find the image to flash?  I'm aware that the firmware is carrier dependent, so I want to know I have the right one.

I'm also aware of TWRP, but I believe the phone needs to be rooted to be able to recover stuff.  But maybe not for the data partition?  Can I install it without OEM unlock enabled?  [This question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131772/recovering-files-in-android-phone-phone-stuck-in-boot-loop) mentions custom recovery, but I'm not sure how it got there (previously installed, or installed while boot looping).

I'm trying to get a clear idea of what I should do.  What is the best way to go about this?  I hesitate to do anything unless I'm sure it's not just going to wipe or brick the thing.  I rooted another phone before and the first attempt failed and wiped it.  I had backed it up, but that's not possible in this case, so whatever I do has to work.

Comment: On a OEM locked device without custom ROM and without ADB access as the system only boot-loops your only chance is flashing a stock firmware. I don't see any other option.

Comment: Doing this will keep the data partition intact and accessible afterwards?

Comment: Usually yes, but I don't know the Samsung firmware upgrade software in detail.

Comment: Well, since you can get adb working can you elevate it to a shell with the command `adb shell` if yes then try to crawl your way through to get the path to your dcim or dcim/camera location with the `ls` command. If you can what is the output from the `ls` command?